# Create objects that are in nested classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have the following class schematic:

```
class ListOfArrays {

class ArrayNode {

    public:

    int* data_;
    int size_;
    ArrayNode* prev_;
    ArrayNode* next_;

    ArrayNode(int* data, int size)
        : data_(data), size_(size), next_(0), prev_(0) {}

};

ArrayNode* head_;
int size_;

public:

ListOfArrays()
    : size_(0), head_(new ArrayNode(0, 0)) {
    head_->next_ = head_;
    head_->prev_ = head_;
}
};
```

How do I create in the main function ArrayNode objects that are all in the ListOfArrays?

Comment: Since `ArrayNode` is a `private` class of `ListOfArrays`, the answer to the question "_How do I create in the main function ArrayNode objects_" is simple: you don't.

Comment: Sounds like `ArrayNode` is an internal module in the `ListOfArrays` class, which you therefore do not want to be using anywhere outside this class (so in `main`, for example, you should only instantiate `ListOfArrays` objects). You should probably rethink your SW design carefully before continuing to implementation.

Comment: Ok, I understood, post this as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the class `ArrayNode` being declared in the private section of `ListOfArrays` which prevents any reference outside of the `ListOfArrays` class.

Comment: While declaring it `public` may resolve the problem "locally" (i.e., fix the compilation error), it is worth noting that the real problem lies in the idea of exposing this functionality - originally intended as an internal mechanism - for external usage to begin with (i.e., the real problem is the general SW design rather than the specific coding error at hand).